# Expected Value Density Functions and Median

Tags: probability, density-function, median

I am trying to understand how we integrate an exp(of a value) and not the exponential function but the expected value function.  My problem is understanding how to exactly setup the integral since I believe the exp should be reflected as E[some value].  Here are the two functions:

I need to find the median of both (set each to 1/2).

The densities are written like this

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}E[\frac{−x}{2}]  $   for  x > 0

Answer here is 1.4

Median of density 
$f(x) = 2xE[−x^2]$ for x>0
Answer here is .83

Comment: No!!  The density involves the exponential function, not the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The median of a random variable with probability density function $f(x)$ is  a number $m$ such that $$\mathbb P(X \le m) = \int_{-\infty}^m f(x)\; dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

$\exp$ is the exponential function.  The expected value is something completely different: $\mathbb E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)\; dx$.

In your first case,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^m f(x)\; dx = \int_0^m \frac12 \exp(-x/2)\; dx = 1 - \exp(-m/2)$$
and this is $1/2$ when $\exp(-m/2) = 1/2$, i.e. $m = 2 \ln(2) \approx 1.386294361$.

Comment: cool thanks.  I will try for the next one